# Prove whether this language is decidable and recognizable

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, formal-languages, decidable

If L1 and L2 are languages we have a new language

```
INTERLACE(L1, L2) = {w1v1w2v2 . . . wnvn | w1w2 . . . wn ∈ L1, v1v2 . . . vn ∈ L2}.
```

For example, if `abc ∈ L1` and `123 ∈ L2`, then `a1b2c3 ∈ INTERLACE(L1, L2)`

How can I prove that the `INTERLACE` is:

1. decidable ?
2. recognizable ?

I know how to show this language is regular.
For decidable I am not so sure..

Here's what I think:

> To show that the class of decidable languages is closed under operation `INTERLACE` need to show that if A and B are two decidable languages, then there is method to find if `INTERLACE` language is decidable. Suppose `A`, `B` decidable languages and `M1`, `M2` two `TM` who decide, respectively.

After I think I have to say how to construct the DFA that recognize the language?

Comment: Probably more suitable for the [cs.se] site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `L1` and `L2` [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language) ==> `INTERLACE(L1, L2)` decidable

Citation from [`Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language):

> There are two equivalent major definitions for the concept of a recursive (also *decidable*) language: 
>      ... 
>      2. A recursive language is a formal language for which there exists a Turing machine that, when presented with any finite input string, halts and accepts if the string is in the language, and halts and rejects otherwise.

Using this definition:

- If `L1` and `L2` are decidable, then algorithms (or Turing machines) `M1` and `M2` exist, so that:

  - `M1` accepts all inputs `w ∈ L1` and rejects all inputs `w ∉ L1`.
  - `M2` accepts all inputs `v ∈ L2` and rejects all inputs `v ∉ L2`.
- Now let's construct algorithm `M` which accepts all inputs `x ∈ INTERLACE(L1, L2)` and rejects all inputs `x ∉ INTERLACE(L1, L2)`, as follows:

  - Given an input `x1 x2 .. xn`.
  - If `n` is odd, reject the input, otherwise (`n` is even):
  - Run `M1` for the input `x1 x3 x5 .. xn-1`. If `M1` rejects this input, then `M` rejects its input and finishes, otherwise (`M1` accepted its input):
  - Run `M2` for the input `x2 x4 x6 .. xn`. If `M2` rejects this input, then `M` rejects its input, otherwise `M` accepts its input.

One can easily prove that `M` is the decision algorithm for `INTERLACE(L1, L2)`, thus, the language is decidable.

## `L1` and `L2` [recognizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language) ==> `INTERLACE(L1, L2)` recognizable

Citation from [`Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language):

> There are three equivalent definitions of a recursively enumerable (also *recognizable*) language: 
>      ... 
>      3. A recursively enumerable language is a formal language for which there exists a Turing machine (or other computable function) that will halt and accept when presented with any string in the language as input but may either halt and reject or loop forever when presented with a string not in the language. Contrast this to recursive languages, which require that the Turing machine halts in all cases.

The proof is very similar to the proof of the 'decidable' property.

- If `L1` and `L2` are recognizable, then algorithms `R1` and `R2` exist, so that:

  - `R1` accepts all inputs `w ∈ L1` and rejects *or loops forever* for all inputs `w ∉ L1`.
  - `R2` accepts all inputs `v ∈ L2` and rejects *or loops forever* for all inputs `v ∉ L2`.
- Let's construct algorithm `R` which accepts all inputs `x ∈ INTERLACE(L1, L2)` and rejects *or loops forever* for all inputs `x ∉ INTERLACE(L1, L2)`:

  - Given an input `x1 x2 .. xn`.
  - If `n` is odd, reject the input, otherwise (`n` is even):
  - Run `R1` for the input `x1 x3 x5 .. xn-1`. If `R1` loops forever, then `R` loops forever as well ("automatically"). If `R1` rejects this input, then `R` rejects its input and finishes, otherwise (if `R1` accepts its input):
  - Run `R2` for the input `x2 x4 x6 .. xn`. If `R2` loops forever, then `R` loops forever as well. If `R2` rejects this input, then `R` rejects its input, otherwise `R` accepts its input.

---

P.S. you were almost there, actually ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the name of the language to INTERLACE actually it was the first name and I changed it to perfectshuffle.